# how can I make a trend line fit close to (0,0) but not include (0,0) in my data?

Tags: fitting

I have five data sets, {4.88281 10^(-5), 0.0788}, {9.76563 10^(-5), 0.1014}, {0.000195313, 0.12455}, {0.000390625, 0.15594}, {0.0015625, 0.18587}. I was using EXCEL to add the trendline, but the x intercept is a negative value. I wanted to fit the trendline close to zero but don't include (0,0) in my plot, can I get this done with Mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to specify a model.  I suspect you want $y=a+b*\log x + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.  If so consider `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: In `FindFit[data,{expr,cons},pars,vars]` , you can add a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{4.88281 10^(-5), 0.0788}, {9.76563 10^(-5), 0.1014}, {0.000195313, 0.12455},
  {0.000390625, 0.15594}, {0.0015625, 0.18587}};

lm = LinearModelFit[data, Log[x], x]
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[data], 
 LogLinearPlot[lm[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image: Data and fit with x on log scale]

```
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Data and fit]